# RTPENGINE Install fail Debian 10

Tags: debian, rtp

Trying to install rtpengine on debian 10.

Failing command

```
dpkg -i ngcp-rtpengine-daemon_*.deb ngcp-rtpengine-iptables_*.deb ngcp-rtpengine-kernel-dkms_*.deb
```

Got this output:

```
"DKMS: install completed.
Job for ngcp-rtpengine-daemon.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status ngcp-rtpengine-daemon.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript ngcp-rtpengine-daemon, action "restart" failed.
● ngcp-rtpengine-daemon.service - NGCP RTP/media Proxy Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ngcp-rtpengine-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-08-02 15:17:50 +06; 14ms ago
  Process: 13363 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/ngcp-rtpengine-iptables-setup start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13379 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rtpengine -f -E --no-log-timestamps --pidfile /run/ngcp-rtpengine-daemon.pid --config-file /etc/rtpengine/rtpengine.conf --table $TABLE (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
  Process: 13380 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/ngcp-rtpengine-iptables-setup stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 13379 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)

Aug 02 15:17:48 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: Starting NGCP RTP/media Proxy Daemon...
Aug 02 15:17:49 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: ngcp-rtpengine-daemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Aug 02 15:17:50 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: ngcp-rtpengine-daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 02 15:17:50 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: Failed to start NGCP RTP/media Proxy Daemon.
Processing triggers for systemd (241-7~deb10u8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ..."
```

In daemon log got this:

```
Aug  2 15:17:32 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: Starting NGCP RTP/media Proxy Daemon...
Aug  2 15:17:32 SoftSwitch ngcp-rtpengine-iptables-setup[11407]: modprobe: FATAL: Module xt_RTPENGINE not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.0-17-amd64
Aug  2 15:17:32 SoftSwitch ngcp-rtpengine-iptables-setup[11407]: iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables): unknown option "--id"
Aug  2 15:17:32 SoftSwitch ngcp-rtpengine-iptables-setup[11407]: Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
Aug  2 15:17:32 SoftSwitch ngcp-rtpengine-iptables-setup[11407]: ip6tables v1.8.2 (nf_tables): unknown option "--id"
Aug  2 15:17:32 SoftSwitch ngcp-rtpengine-iptables-setup[11407]: Try `ip6tables -h' or 'ip6tables --help' for more information.
Aug  2 15:17:32 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: ngcp-rtpengine-daemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Aug  2 15:17:33 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: ngcp-rtpengine-daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug  2 15:17:33 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: Failed to start NGCP RTP/media Proxy Daemon.
Aug  2 15:17:48 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Succeeded.
Aug  2 15:17:48 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: Stopped Load Kernel Modules.
Aug  2 15:17:48 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: Stopping Load Kernel Modules...
Aug  2 15:17:48 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
Aug  2 15:17:48 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
Aug  2 15:17:48 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: Reloading.
Aug  2 15:17:48 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: Starting NGCP RTP/media Proxy Daemon...
Aug  2 15:17:49 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: ngcp-rtpengine-daemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Aug  2 15:17:50 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: ngcp-rtpengine-daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug  2 15:17:50 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: Failed to start NGCP RTP/media Proxy Daemon.
Aug  2 15:17:50 SoftSwitch systemd[1]: Reloading.
```

Can someone please tell me where to dig? Got no idea. Thanks!

Comment: This site for questions in russian.

Answer (score 0):

Глянь `dkms status`, попробуй пересобрать модуль rtpengine-kernel-dkms

```
dkms install xt_RTPENGINE/<module-version> -k 4.19.0-17
```